# Sorting graphQL data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, graphql

Very much appreciated for reading this one! It might seem like easy for you, but I am quite new, so bear with me. I have a query in GraphQL which gives me the following results:

```
  "data": {
"completeglobaldata": [
      {
        "increasehotdays": 43,
        "countryname": "Afghanistan"
      },
      {
        "increasehotdays": 66.1,
        "countryname": "Angola"
      },
      {
        "increasehotdays": 0,
        "countryname": "Anguilla"
      },
      {
        "increasehotdays": 0,
        "countryname": "Åland Islands"
      },
      {
        "increasehotdays": 51.9,
        "countryname": "Albania"
      },
]
}
```

Yet, now I want to sort the data in a descending way with JavaScript sort. The problem is that GraphQL will return objects and I do not understand how this would work.. I have been stuck on [the array/sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) page for some good hours now.

```
export const sortDescendingHotDays = (completeglobaldata) => {
  const countryTemperatures = completeglobaldata.map((country) => ({
    ...completeglobaldata,
  }));

  return completeglobaldata.sort((a, b) =>
    a.country.increasehotdays < b.country.increasehotdays ? 1 : -1
  );
};
```

This is obviously wrong, but it shows how lost I am. Oh, I am using React by the way. Ofcourse I could easily change the graphQL query to :

```
query MyQuery {
  completeglobaldata(order_by: {increasehotdays: desc}) {
    increasehotdays
    countryname
  }
}
```

But this is not possible in my situation.I really need to get the data and then sort it using Javascript sort

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Can you log the value of `completeglobaldata` for us to see?

Comment: `countryname` not `country` in sort

Comment: This is how two objects look like: 

```{
    __typename: 'completeglobaldata',
    avdaysabove95F19862005: 50.3,
    avdaysabove95F20202039: 73.4,
    avdaysabove95F20402059: 95.1,
    increasehotdays: 126.8
 countryname: 'Guinea',
  },
{
    __typename: 'completeglobaldata',
    avdaysabove95F19862005: 40.5,
    avdaysabove95F20202039: 73.4,
    avdaysabove95F20402059: 99.1,
    increasehotdays: 80
    countryname: 'Gibraltar',
  },

```

Comment: ```export const sortDescendingHotDays = (filteredCountries) => {
  const countryTemperatures = filteredCountries.map((countryname) => ({
    ...filteredCountries,
  }));

  return filteredCountries.sort((a, b) =>
    a.countryname.increasehotdays < b.countryname.increasehotdays ? 1 : -1
  );
};
```
Alright, it does not give me any errors, but it does not seem to sort properly though when I run it :

```sortDescendingHotDays(filteredCountries);```

Comment: you should mention WHAT field/prop you want to sort on !!! your code was about `country` but taking wrong prop because there is no `country` prop in array elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close!   There isn’t a country key on your individual objects, and when you’re using sort, you’re already comparing two different country objects.

```
completeglobaldata.sort((a,b) => b.increasehotdays - a.increasehotdays)
```

Comment: Oh my God, this is it! Now I just have to link this to a button I guess. I did not even need to  map it like this: ```completeglobaldata.map((countryname) => ..... ```, could you explain me why?

Comment: I was actually confused about what your map was doing, since you assigned the map function to a variable and didn’t use it (countryTemperatures).  If you’re asking why you don’t have to assign the sort to anything, it’s because sort manipulates the input array rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Aha, clear. Now I do have one issue though, this way my data does not sort perfectly, as some high days still end up somewhere near the end. I guess this is caused because this sorting algorithm swaps the one next to it, right? What would be a better way of sorting this? (its actually a dataset with 250 countries) Thanks a lot for helping Amy! And you have a cool webpage ;)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort   Actually, it’s more to do with how you’re telling it to sort.  Since the values are numeric, you actually want something more like ```completeglobaldata.sort((a,b) => b.increasehotdays - a.increasehotdays)```

Comment: You are right! I should definitely follow more JavaScript classes. I am ashamed I don't understand this logic yet.

Comment: It helps to work through some examples by hand, but in order for the sort to work, it needs some way of determining “greater than 0”, “0”, and “less than 0”.   When you subtract a number from another number, those are the only three outcomes, so it just works (whereas when you do string comparison you have to tell it what is greater than 0 — 1 — and what is less than 0 — -1).  If this answer solves your question don’t forget to accept it as an answer.  :)

Comment: Hey thanks Amy! How to accept this as an answer? Also, one more question: if I wanted to export some of these sorting methods, like 
 ``export const sortMostHotDays ```
and then have this and some others as a "queryFilter"" and "setQueryFilter":

which eventually ends as: ``` queryFilter (completeglobaldata)```

Why is it then that React says : "queryFilter is not a function"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  As for your question, there's not enough context for me to be able to answer and SO comments aren't really the place to ask additional questions unrelated to the original question.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand the comment system yet. Anyway, if someone is interested in the future, I asked a follow-up question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65933392/passing-a-function-to-state-in-react

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation : [filtering-pagination-and-sorting-GRAPHQL](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/). 
 I hope it should helps you

Comment: But this is in GraphQL itself right? I mean, I could easily adjust the query to ```query MyQuery {
  completeglobaldata(order_by: {increasehotdays: desc}) {
    increasehotdays
    countryname
  }
}
```

but thats not possible in my situation. I need to sort it with Javascript inside React.