# Passing a function to State in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am new to React and have a question regarding passing down functions in a state. I have a couple of 'sorting functions' in my util folder, which look like this:

```
export const sortColdestSummerCountries = (filteredCountries) => {
  return filteredCountries.sort(
    (a, b) => a.avsummertemp20802099 - b.avsummertemp20802099
  );
};
```

and a few others:
`sortHighestSummerTemp, sortLargestIncreaseHotDays, sortColdestSummerCountries, sortMostColdDays, sortWorstAffectedCountries` which pretty much look similar. I use them to sort my data by users' request, and if I wrap `sortHighestSummerTemp(filteredCountries)` around my data, it works as a charm.

Now the issue: because I will have eventually 10+ filters, it makes sense to me to create a global `const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState({ sortHighestSummerTemp});` which then responds to `const onChangeQueryFilter = (e) => { setQueryFilter(e.target.value); };`

Yet, upon trying  `queryFilter (filteredCountries)` the terminal shows me  `"queryFilter is not a function"` when I filter it? It's still the same  sortHighestSummerTemp function right or what am I missing here? Do I summarize this problem correctly?

Hopefully it was clear and you understand what I am trying to do. Could anyone explain me what is going on and what's the best practice here?

UPDATE:
Prateek suggested the following:

`function sortBy(filteredCountries, sortKey) {     return [...filteredCountries].sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);   }    const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState({     sortMostHotDays,   });    const filteredData = sortBy(filteredCountries, sortMostHotDays);    console.log(filteredData);`

This does not work, it still shows the old data (filteredCountries) but the filtering does not work. Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

## 1st approach

- You are putting string into your state. Maybe it's better if you use an object with sort functions and use user input as key to the sorting functions object

```
const onChangeQueryFilter = (e) => { setQueryFilter(e.target.value); };


const sortingFns = {
  "temp": sortHighestSummerTemp, 
  "hot": sortLargestIncreaseHotDays, 
  "summer": sortColdestSummerCountries, 
  "cold": sortMostColdDays,
   .....
}

const sortedData = sortingFns[queryFilter](data);
```

### 2nd Approach

- It is much better if you pass sorting parameter to your factory of sorting functions.

```
function sortBy(data, sortKey) {
  return [...data].sort((a, b) => a[key] - b[key])
}

// the query filter should respond to the key on which you should sort the data.
const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = React.useState('');
const filteredData = sortBy(data, queryFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Let me get into the details:

On the 1st approach : ```TypeError: sortingFns[queryFilter] is not a function```



On the second approach:
```function sortBy(filteredCountries, sortKey) {
    return [...filteredCountries].sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);
  }

  const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = React.useState({
    sortHighestSummerTemp,
  });

  const filteredData = sortBy(filteredCountries, queryFilter);```

The data remains exactly the same, doesn't sort. It gives no errors, yet "filteredData" doesn't actually do anything right now.

Comment: @BridlerShoc  can you create a reproducible issue in stackblitz? 
On first approach, the state of your component should map into the keys of `sortingFns`. Don't store functions in the state. In second approach, you should pass the key on which the data should be sorted.

Comment: " In second approach, you should pass the key on which the data should be sorted" What do you mean by this?


I can't make the issue in stackblitz. My skills are lacking in this, and the issue is too specific to simplify for me. I could show you what I am doing if you have Discord or something :)

Comment: ```function sortBy(filteredCountries, sortKey) {
    return [...filteredCountries].sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);
  }

  const [queryFilter, setQueryFilter] = useState({
    sortMostHotDays,
  });

  const filteredData = sortBy(filteredCountries, sortMostHotDays);

  console.log(filteredData);```

Do you mean this? Because it does show the data, but the filtering does not work like this, it's still the same.

Comment: Like you want to sort on "avsummertemp20802099", that should be passed an the sortKey to the sortBy function.

Comment: ```const filteredData = sortBy(
    filteredCountries,
    filteredCountries.avsummertemp20802099
  ); ```

Aah.. this does not sort the data yet.. If I do it just "avsummertemp20802099", then it states  ```ReferenceError: avsummertemp20802099 is not defined```